# Subsetting Data at Once

Tags: r, subset

I am using a dataset (*myData*) that observes water runoff (variable *y*) for different types of plants (variable *plant*); there are 15 types of plants in the data. I am trying to subset the data multiple times so that I have 15 subsets of data, one for each type of plant. I tried doing so by doing the following loop:

```
k = 1
for(i in unique(myData$plant)){
  myData[[k]] = subset(myData, plant = i)
  k = k+1
}
```

My goal is to have data sets such that *myData1* has data only from the first plant, *myData2* has data only from the second plant, *myData3* to have data only on the third, and so on. I cannot find a way to name each data set each level of *k* (e.g. *myDatak* for each data set, so the naming will automatically change for each *k*).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `?split` from base R. `split` will create a list of dataframes each containing a group -

```
df_by_plants <- split(myData, myData$plant)

names(df_by_plants) <- paste0("myData", seq_along(df_by_plants))
```

Comment: This is very helpful! But like I said, I want to have the different data sets in the form *myData1* for each plant (so in your answer, I would want *myData1* to be the same as *df_by_plants$'first plant'*. In other words, naming the new data frames is my main issue (I could manually assign each of these, but I want to do it in a more efficient way).

Comment: Is there any way I can just have, for example, *myData1*, on its own? As it currently stands, if I want *myData1*, I have to write out *df_by_plants$myData1*. I would like to only have to type out *myData1*.

Comment: you can simplify the names if it's too cumbersome ex. `dbp$md1` doesn't seem verbose. Anyways if you must have individual objects you can use this at the end - `lapply(names(df_by_plants), function(n) assign(n, df_by_plants[[n]], envir = .GlobalEnv))`. I don't recommend this. Keeping all the dfs in a list is cleaner/better.